# Setting a couchdb maximum database size

Tags: couchdb

What is the best way to restrict the size of an individual couchdb database? My server has thousands of databases for allowing users to sync with (kind of like dropbox) and I need to put restrictions on the maximum size.

I am able to use an external process to poll the database for size, but it seems unsatisfactory to be doing this to thousands of databases at a regular intervals -- and even in a short period like an hour .. it is very easy for a user to sync and massively exceed my database size constraint.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Was ulimit the answer? I am trying to do the same thing with a CouchDB Docker Image on an AWS EC2 instance.

Answer (score 3):

Because couchdb operates under the assumption that disk is cheap, it doesn't provide a way to limit database size.   You can reduce the database size by regularly compacting the database and views.

As a workaround, if you're running couchdb on Linux, you can limit file size for the couchdb user with `ulimit -f`.  Note that this would also affect log files, so make sure logs are rotated under this limit.

I haven't tried this, and doubt that couchdb/erlang will handle a file over the limit size as elegantly as you might like (probably similar to a disk filling).  However, at least this would keep a user from DOS'ing your service.